# I am using unpivot and i want o change returned unpivot cloumn value

Tags: oracle

I am using the below query

```
select ORDER_ID, 
       CLUB_ID, 
       Product_Code, 
       Qty  
  from testing_temp
  unpivot(
    (Product_Code, Qty)
        FOR  prod IN( (PRO_NO_T, QTY_T),
                      (PRO_NO_H, QTY_H)
                     )
        )
```

My result of the query:

```
ORDER_ID    CLUB_ID PRODUCT_CODE    QTY

1082        6601    935944          10
1082        6601    783800          10
1083        6601    935944          10
1083        6601    783800          22
1081        6601    935944          10
1081        6601    783800          12
```

But my expected result should be like below(have to change the `PRODUCT_CODE` with static value i.e For column `PRO_NO_T` value should be `TTTT` and `PRO_NO_H` value should be `HHHH`).

```
ORDER_ID    CLUB_ID PRODUCT_CODE    QTY

1082        6601    TTTT            10
1082        6601    HHHH            10
1083        6601    TTTT            10
1083        6601    HHHH            22
1081        6601    TTTT            10
1081        6601    HHHH            12
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.